# Flutter pass value to bloc repository

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to study bloc in flutter. I have bloc, events and repository files. I know how to pass data between pages, but i can't pass the parameter to the repository
I need to pass a parameter to the repository for make query to db. For example category id

**products_by_category_repository.dart**

```
import 'package:billfort/models/products_model.dart';
import 'package:billfort/strings/strings.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

abstract class ProductsByCategoryRepository {
  Future<List<HydraMember>> getProducts();
}

class ProductsByCategoryRepositoryImpl implements ProductsByCategoryRepository {

  @override
  Future<List<HydraMember>> getProducts() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse("${AppStrings.api}products?category=here need pass id"));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      List<HydraMember> products = Products.fromJson(data).hydraMember;
      return products;
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }

}
```

**products_bloc.dart**

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:billfort/bloc/products_event.dart';
import 'package:billfort/bloc/products_state.dart';
import 'package:billfort/models/products_model.dart';
import 'package:billfort/repository/products_repository.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class ProductsBloc extends Bloc < ProductsEvent, ProductsState > {

    ProductsRepository repository;

    ProductsBloc({
        @required this.repository
    }): super(null);

    @override
    // TODO: implement initialState
    ProductsState get initialState => ProductsInitialState();

    @override
    Stream < ProductsState > mapEventToState(ProductsEvent event) async *{
        if (event is FetchProductsEvent) {
            yield ProductsLoadingState();
            try {
                List < HydraMember > products = await repository.getProducts();
                yield ProductsLoadedState(products: products);
            } catch (e) {
                yield ProductsErrorState(message: e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your process of fetching products needs input, then your class `FetchProductsEvent` should have a property that provides that input, just as your state class `ProductsLoadedState` for example has a `products` property that provides the output.

That said, did you upgrade your bloc package without really understanding the changes? Why are you passing `null` to your base constructor, but still providing an overload for `initialState`? Your base constructor should get `ProductsInitialState()` directly and you should remove the overload. If it does not fire warnings for you, you may want to crank up your compiler settings, so your compiler can guide you better.

Comment: I removed super(null) in ProductsBloc now. Have warning in ide but work fine

Comment: if for the same instance of the bloc category_id will stay the same then pass it to the bloc contructor, otherwise as @nvoigt wrote pass it using the `FetchProductsEvent`